# A simple JS question about 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript

here is a simple example about 'this' keyword

```
var a = 10;
var obj = {
  a: 20
};

function fn() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

fn(); // 10
fn.call(obj); // 20
```

however, when I try to run it, the result shown as below.

```
undefined
20
```

why the first call return undefined? I don't get it. Can somebody help explain it to me? Many thanks

Comment: If you copy-paste that into a console, it'll log `10`. If you're running this in some online Javascript interpreter, you're probably not actually running this code in global scope and hence will see a different behaviour.

Comment: @deceze it only displays `10` if strict mode is NOT activated right?